# What is the cleanest way to do an outer join without equals?

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

I have two lists, I need to find the items in the first list that are missing from the second, but I can only compare them with a Boolean function.

```
class A
{
    internal bool Matching(A a)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class OuterMatch
{
    List<A> List1 = new List<A>();
    List<A> List2 = new List<A>();

    void BasicOuterJoin()
    {
        // textbook example of an outer join, but it does not use my Matching function
        var missingFrom2 = from one in List1
                           join two in List2
                           on one equals two into matching
                           from match in matching.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where match == null
                           select one;
    }

    void Matching()
    {
        // simple use of the matching function, but this is an inner join.
        var matching = from one in List1
                       from two in List2
                       where one.Matching(two)
                       select one;
    }

    void MissingBasedOnMatching()
    {
        // a reasonable substitute for what I'm after
        var missingFrom2 = from one in List1
                           where (from two in List2
                                  where two.Matching(one)
                                  select two)
                                  .Count() == 0
                           select one;
    }
```

`MissingBasedOnMatching` gives me the right results, but it's not visually obviously an outer join like `BasicOuterJoin` is.  Is there a clearer way to do this?

There's a form of GroupJoin that takes a comparison operator, but I'm not clear if there is a way to use it to make an outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem statement is actually

> Find all members of X that do not exist in Y

And given a class `Foo` that implements `IEquatable<Foo>` (pretty much what your `Matching` method does):

```
class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals( Foo other )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then this code should give you what you want:

```
List<Foo> x       = GetFirstList() ;
List<Foo> y       = GetSecondList() ;
List<Foo> xNotInY = x.Where( xItem => ! y.Any( yItem => xItem.Equals(yItem) ) ).ToList() ;
```

You should bear in mind that this runs in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time. Consequently, you might want to implement an `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` and put your second list in a `HashSet<Foo>`:

```
class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool  Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if ( x == null )
        {
            return y == null ;
        }
        else if ( y == null ) return false ;
        else
        {
            return x.Equals(y) ;
        }
    }

    public int  GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode() ;
    }
}
```

Then do something like

```
List<Foo>    x       = GetFirstList() ;
List<Foo>    y       = GetSecondList() ;
HashSet<Foo> yLookup = new HashSet<Foo>( y , new FooComparer() ) ;
List<Foo>    xNotInY = x.Where( x => !yLookup.Contains(x) ) ;
```

You'll incur some overhead in constructing the hash set (1 pass through the second list), but subsequent lookups via `Contains()` are O(1).

If you look at the sources for the Linq join operation, this is close to what it does.

It wouldn't be difficult to strip the Linq sources for Join() and it's helpers and tweak them to product left and right join operators instead of the stock inner join.

Comment: Getting there...  I can't overwrite Foo, but I could write a new FooComarer, and it's slightly less overhead than the LINQHelper solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using some useful (and short!) code [from a blog by Ed Khoze](http://www.edkhoze.com/a-few-useful-ienumerable-extension-methods).

He's posted a handy class which provides an adapter so that you can use `Enumerable.Except()` with a lambda.

Once you have that code, you can use `Except()` to solve your problem like so:

```
var missing = list1.Except(list2, (a, b) => a.Matching(b));
```

Here's a complete compilable sample. Credit to Ed Khoze for the `LINQHelper` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class A
    {
        public int Value;

        public bool Matching(A a)
        {
            return a.Value == Value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        void test()
        {
            var list1 = new List<A>();
            var list2 = new List<A>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) list1.Add(new A {Value = i});
            for (int i = 4; i < 16; ++i) list2.Add(new A {Value = i});

            var missing = list1.Except(list2, (a, b) => a.Matching(b));

            missing.Print(); // Prints 0 1 2 3 16 17 18 19
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().test();
        }
    }

    static class MyEnumerableExt
    {
        public static void Print<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
        {
            foreach (var item in sequence)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public static class LINQHelper
    {
        private class LambdaComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<T>
        {
            private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _lambdaComparer;
            private readonly Func<T, int> _lambdaHash;

            public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer) :
                this(lambdaComparer, o => 0)
            {
            }

            private LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer, Func<T, int> lambdaHash)
            {
                if (lambdaComparer == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaComparer");
                if (lambdaHash == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaHash");
                _lambdaComparer = lambdaComparer;
                _lambdaHash = lambdaHash;
            }
            public bool Equals(T x, T y)
            {
                return _lambdaComparer(x, y);
            }
            public int GetHashCode(T obj)
            {
                return _lambdaHash(obj);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>
        (
            this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, 
            IEnumerable<TSource> second, 
            Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparer
        )
        {
            return enumerable.Except(second, new LambdaComparer<TSource>(comparer));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution if you have to do it multiple times and be worth all the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for your purposes?

```
var missing = List1.Except(List2);
```

If you need custom comparison logic you can build a custom IEqualityComparer. Note however that `Except` treats both lists as sets, so it will eliminate duplicates from List1.

Comment: I need custom comparison logic, and I can't edit A directly.  To further complicate matters, A.Equals has been overridden already with a different comparison operator than the one I need.